# Sound lower than usual

Tags: sound

The sound seems quite low than when I used Windows. I recently changed. What might be causing it?
I tried the sound box on another device and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I switched I found the same issue - it was just a matter of turning up the volume in the sound settings.  I know that seems an obvious answer, but just in case you didn't think of it.Click on the speaker from the icons at the very top right of your desktop, choose SOUND SETTINGS and check your output volume.  Mine, by default, was set very low.  Since you said you just recently made the change - I thought I'd start with the easiest possibility first.

While you're there - check your INPUT and MIC settings too.... I had to increase mine to use my camera mic.